# In MS Excel, How can I ONLY lock row 3 when scrolling (Not the top row aswell)

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I only lock the one row when scrolling?

I don't want rows 1 & 2 to display at all when scrolling down, just row 3

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure you can't.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking, tried playing around with some freeze options and split options but they all seem to include all the rows above the one I want to freeze aswell

Comment: So what did you have in mind should happen for the rows above the one that is frozen? E.g. if row 10 would be frozen, what should happen with rows 1..9 when you scroll down a few rows, or a page full of rows? And when you scroll back up?

Comment: Just that they would scroll with the rest of the document and row 10 would act as if it was the top row that was frozen.

So when being at the top of the document, rows would appear as normal, but when you scroll down past row 10, it would basically become stuck/frozen as the top row as you scroll down, much like it would if I'd have just frozen the top row.

Comment: You could probably write some VBA to do this ...

Comment: " 1 & 2 to display at all " --> you may just 'hide' the row. [ `r-click > hide` ]

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you want, but can't you scroll down so row 3 is the 1st visible row, then freeze it?